# Add an attribute to an HTML element

Tags: php, html

I can't quite figure it out, I'm looking for some code that will add an attribute to an HTML element.

For example lets say I have a string with an `<a>` in it, and that `<a>` needs an attribute added to it, so `<a>` gets added `style="xxxx:yyyy;"`. How would you go about doing this?

Ideally it would add any attribute to any tag.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: I actually wrote a php function to do that... wanted to search for all hyperlinks in a block of text, and created a target='blank' attribute, or changed the existing one to be target='blank'.  It was a pretty complex process, regex matching was just a small part.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's been said a million times. Don't use regex's for HTML parsing.

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $x = new DOMXPath($dom);

    foreach($x->query("//a") as $node)
    {   
        $node->setAttribute("style","xxxx");
    }
    $newHtml = $dom->saveHtml()
```

Comment: How would you prevent `DOMDocument()` adding `<html>` wrapper around the given tag?

Comment: Use another language. Joke aside, since DOMDocument is essentially crap you have to do some str_replace on the document to remove anything it added

Comment: You can use `$node->c14n()` to get the canonical HTML for the node.  It won't wrap in `<html>` tags.

Comment: There are some quite good reasons to use Regex to parse HTML... Though in this case you are right, the OP should not aim for regex but for some other solution.

Answer (score 9):

Here is using regex:

```
  $result = preg_replace('/(<a\b[^><]*)>/i', '$1 style="xxxx:yyyy;">', $str);
```

but Regex cannot parse malformed HTML documents.

Comment: Why do you need the `<` in `[^><]`?

Comment: To prevent accident possibility, that is, the regex will not process `a` tags which doesn't properly closed, for example: `<a href="xxx" <p>yyy</p>`; in this case, if I didn't include the `<`, the regex will consider the scope of `a` tag is `<a href="xxx" <p>`.

Comment: ...or if someone decides to include `<` as a literal character inside an attribute. Better fail the match then instead of messing up the HTML even further.